# CUDA: Is there a drawback when using kernel parameters vs. copy to symbol?

Tags: cuda

Supposed that my CUDA kernel has a long list of parameters. For convenience, i put these in a struct:

```
struct params {
  int firstParam;
  float secondParam;
  ...
  bool lastParam;
}
```

Is there a disadvantage when calling the kernel with

```
myKernel<<<n,m>>>( params );
```

compared to first copying to constant memory?

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol( paramsOnDevice, &paramsOnHost, sizeof(params), 0 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On devices of compute capability 2.0 and later the limit for the size of the kernel arguments is 4KB (see the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-parameters)). This means that if your structure is very large then you could run into this limit, but otherwise the behaviour is more-or-less the same since the arguments are passed via constant memory.

One case where copying to a symbol may have a very small benefit is where you launch the same kernel many times with the same arguments, copying explicitly means you only copy once instead of every time. However I would expect the benefit to be small in most practical cases - you could measure this if you were worried!